# Regex for float number list

Tags: regex, notepad++

i need help with regex (and maybe Notepad++).

Lets say I have a list of floats seperated by commas with line breaks like

```
54.762523,23.765532,0.762334,12;
14.932523,13.265332,0.422334,12;
76.762831,18.655239,0.717822,13;
```

Now I want to delete all lines where the third float in each line is less than 0.7.

The resulting list would be:

```
54.762523,23.765532,0.762334,12;
76.762831,18.655239,0.717822,13;
```

Can I solve this with regex and Notepad++?

If regex fails, what would you recommend?

Comment: In the last line of your sample input, should there be decimal points or commas in the numbers (i.e. 18,655239,0,717822 or 18.655239,0.717822)?

Comment: Decimal point, thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/kKJ6zm/1) a try.

`^(\d+(\.\d+)?,){2}0?\.[0-6].*$`

Comment: To delete the *line*, you probably want to add `\R` to the end so it's nuked too, otherwise you'll get blank lines rather than deleting them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. (*Yes, this works in NP++*)

Globally Find `(?m)^(?:(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+),){2}0*\.[0-6].*\R?`
Replace with nothing

Readable version

```
 (?m)                          # Multi-line mode

 ^                             # BOL
 (?:                           # First 2 float + ,
      (?:
           \d+ 
           (?: \. \d* )?
        |  \. \d+ 
      )
      ,
 ){2}
 0* \. [0-6]                   # Third float less than .7
 .*                            # Rest of line
 \R?                           # Optional line break
```